# extracting a .ppm.bz2 from a custom path to a custom path

Tags: python, extract, bzip2, tarfile, bz2

as the title says, I have several folders, several .ppm.bz2 files and I want to extract them exactly where they are using python.

[Directory structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3vpB.png)

I am traversing in the folders as this:

```
 import tarfile
 import os
 path = '/Users/ankitkumar/Downloads/colorferet/dvd1/data/images/'
 folders = os.listdir(path)
 for folder in folders:  #the folders starting like 00001
     if not folder.startswith("0"):
         pass
     path2 = path + folder
     zips = os.listdir(path2)
     for zip in zips:
         if not zip.startswith("0"):
             pass
         path3 = path2+"/"+zip

         fh = tarfile.open(path3, 'r:bz2')
         outpath = path2+"/"
         fh.extractall(outpath)
         fh.close
```

`

then I get this error
`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ZIP.py", line 16, in <module>
    fh = tarfile.open(path3, 'r:bz2')
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1693, in open
    return func(name, filemode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1778, in bz2open
    t = cls.taropen(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1723, in taropen
    return cls(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1587, in __init__
    self.firstmember = self.next()
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2370, in next
    raise ReadError(str(e))
tarfile.ReadError: invalid header
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tarfile module is for tar files, including `tar.bz2`. if your file is not `tar` you should use `bz2` module directly.

Also, try using `os.walk` instead of multiple `listdir` as it can traverse the tree

```
import os
import bz2
import shutil

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext.lower() != '.bz2':
            continue
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
        newname = os.path.join(path, basename)
        with bz2.open(fullname) as fh, open(newname, 'wb') as fw:
            shutil.copyfileobj(fh, fw)
```

This will uncompress all `.bz2` files in all subfolders, in the same place they are. All other files will stay the same. If the uncompressed file already exists it will be overwritten.

*Please backup your data before running destructive code*

Comment: but problem is not getting the bz2 file, I want the exact path for getting the file as well as extracting the ppm at that place.
moreover after doing this, I got the error
`
/Users/ankitkumar/Downloads/colorferet/dvd1/data/images/00658/00658_941121_hr.ppm.bz2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "File.py", line 12, in <module>
    fh = tarfile.open(fullname)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1680, in open
    raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
`

Comment: @ankiiiiiii That's what the code above will do - did you try it? The exact path is in the `path` variable.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii you shouldn't use the tarfile module. I edited the answer.

Comment: am I missing something?


with bz2.open(fullname) as fh, bz2.open(newname, 'wb') as fw:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'

Comment: are you using python 3.3 or above? https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html#bz2.open @ankiiiiiii if python 2 use `bz2.BZ2File` instead of `bz2.open`

Comment: it is 2.7, should the file exist firsthand to write upon? as after changing open, it shows: permission denied 
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/ankitkumar/Downloads/colorferet/dvd1/data/images/00658/00658_941121_hr.ppm'

Comment: No, the file doesn't have to exist. That error means the user running the script has no permission to write to that folder - you need to give that user permission (or run the code with another user that can write there)

Comment: okay... I have done sudo, its running, even copying took 3 minutes...its taking time.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii yup - `bz2` is a complex compression format and decompressing it takes time.

Comment: the question is still open...files are corrupted. it is like just the extension has been removed without actually opening it. the file size also remains the same.

Comment: If you're using `bz2.BZ2File` then the files have been uncompressed. I actually tried the code in a folder here and it works fine @ankiiiiiii

Comment: yes I used bz2.BZ2File

is there something like closing the file too? or maybe with ppm file type

Comment: The `with` statement already closes the file for you, it is definitely working fine here.